# PowerQuery - Subquery

Tags: powerquery

I am looking for a way to assess, and display graphically, the worklaod of two teams.

On one hand, I have a data set with projects as rows and start and end date for each of the Teams, A and B.

[Sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/okEgu.png)

On the other hand, I have a dataset with all days increments.

What I would want is the count of active projects each day for each team. In SQL, I would try a subquery...

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I would build a Query against each data set (you probably already have these), then I would add a Custom Column to each e.g.

```
Dummy Merge Key 
= 1
```

Then I would add a Merge step to the "Projects" query to combine it with the "days" query, joining on the Dummy Merge Key.  Then I would expand the resulting NewColumn to get the required "days" query columns (e.g. Date).

At this point you have a cross-join (in SQL terms). Next I would add a Custom/Conditional column, e.g.

```
Include Date
= [Start_TEAM_1] >= [Date] and [End_TEAM_1] <= [Date]
```

You can then filter on the resulting column = true to only keep the rows with [Date] values within the Start-End ranges.

Obviously your "Projects" data structure (with duplicated Start & End columns) is awkward for this purpose - I would probably unpivot it first to avoid having repeated code and confusing criteria.

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if this is still required (anyway, maybe someone else will also find it useful). :)

I can offer this solution:

```
    let
    //Create example source tables
    Projects = Table.FromColumns(
        {
            {"P001","P002"}, 
            {#date(2016,10,06), #date(2016,10,11)}, 
            {#date(2016,10,11), #date(2016,10,16)}, 
            {#date(2016,10,16), #date(2016,10,21)}, 
            {#date(2016,10,24), #date(2016,10,29)}
        }, 
        {"Project_No", "Start_Team_1", "End_Team_1", "Start_Team_2", "End_Team_2"}),
    Dates = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Table.FromColumns({List.Transform({1..31}, each #date(2016,10,_))}, {"Date"}),{{"Date", type date}}),

    //Add dummy columns, join, remove dummy columns
    Join = Table.RemoveColumns(
                 Table.Join(
                           Table.AddColumn(Dates, "tmp1", each 1), {"tmp1"}, 
                           Table.AddColumn(Projects, "tmp2", each 1), {"tmp2"},
                           JoinKind.FullOuter
                           )
           , {"tmp1", "tmp2"}),

    //Group dates and count required rows
    GetResult = Table.Group(Join, {"Date"}, 
            {
                {"Team1_Prj_Count", each Table.RowCount(Table.SelectRows(_, each [Start_Team_1] <= [Date] and [End_Team_1] >= [Date])), type number},
                {"Team2_Prj_Count", each Table.RowCount(Table.SelectRows(_, each [Start_Team_2] <= [Date] and [End_Team_2] >= [Date])), type number}
            })
in
    GetResult
```

Seem to solve your problem.